# Social Studio contacts on MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-contacts, social

does anyone know if it's possible to transfer contacts from Social Studio to Marketing Cloud? I would like to capture data about those clients that use social accounts in order to create a list or Data Extension on Marketing Cloud.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only do this via macros that create a lead in Sales Cloud or a Case in Service Cloud. That data can obviously be synced to Marketing Cloud (import or connector).

Answer (score 0):

social persona can be leveraged, thats gets created within service cloud when the post is moved from social studio to salesforce. However social persona is publicly available information coming in from twitter or Facebook, which may or may not give you contact details for all the personas. If available, you you can leverage that to run further campaigns.